# jqueryui icons not showing two spans next to each other

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I'm trying to get two icons in separate spans next to an input.

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/kralco626/K6TzK/2/

However, the second icon doesn't show up...

In the end I want the input and the two spans on the same line and I need to be able to hide/show the spans.

update: Got the icons to show but not working with ui-state-error

I have the exact code here:

http://jsfiddle.net/kralco626/K6TzK/5/

and get this:

[image]

Comment: This: http://jsfiddle.net/kralco626/K6TzK/3/ is my approach for making them appear on the same line... however the second icon still doesn't show up???

Comment: Got an example to show it not working: http://jsfiddle.net/kralco626/K6TzK/7/

Comment: however, i'm going to create a new question for it.

Comment: New question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6357335/jqueryui-icon-in-span-not-working-on-dialog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<span>` has to have an `</span>` at the end. `<span />` is not valid.

Comment: really? you can do that with every other tag can't you?

Comment: you can do it with `$('<span />')` but not in plain HTML. jQuery handles that for you and it may be valid XML but if you explore the DOM in firebug you will see, that firefox will add end tags, and so nest the 2nd span into the first.