# JqueryUI icon with ui-state-error not working in dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a ninput and two spans, each with a jquery ui icon that I am trying to display inline in a jquery ui dialog.

The problem occurs when I try to apply ui-state-error to the span.

Outside the dialog the icons works fine, inside the dialog however the icon does not show up correctly... !

[image]

Ideas???

http://jsfiddle.net/kralco626/K6TzK/8/

Comment: is everyone else at least getting the same effect as me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you give your popup `div` an `ID`, you add the following to your CSS  to fix the issue:

```
#popupDiv > .ui-state-error { 
    background-position: -32px -192px; 
}
```

That should cause minimal impact on whatever else you have on the page.

[**Demo on jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Town/PyAVx/)

Comment: Ya, I guess I could also just set background and border color to red... both seem like bad solutions... seems like a bug in jqueryui to me...

Answer (score 1):

The `ui-state-error` class on the first `<span>` is causing the problem with the icon inside the widget.

The jQuery UI theme css has a different `background` rule when inside a widget, that is overriding the other background.

```
.ui-state-error, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-error, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-error {border: 1px solid #cd0a0a; background: #fef1ec url(images/ui-bg_glass_95_fef1ec_1x400.png) 50% 50% repeat-x; color: #cd0a0a; }
```

You could remove the `ui-state-error` class from your `<span>`s to fix it but that may not be exactly what you are after if you *need* the red "alert" outline.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the problem isn't just in the Error its any widget within a dialog.  I'm note sure why but the CSS weights become different when within the dialog.

Anyway long story short you just need to add CSS for the icons you need to use:

```
#popupDiv > .ui-icon-circle-close { 
    background-position: -32px -192px;
}
```

As can be seen in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8J395/

Hope it helps someone.